Use cookies to save user ID of person who makes the login in ASP.NET MVC
I am working on an ASP.NET MVC app. I want to make a program using cookies such that the user that is making the login and adding or modifying the content, their name/ID should be stored in the index table.
model.createdby = User.Identity.Name; 

But I want a common cookie class that should be used

ASP.NET's authentication system already does this for you.

You can use Sessions:
example:
Session["LOGIN_DATA"] = USER_OBJECT

This can save the user data to session once user log in
in View , you can use it to verify user :
@if(Session["LOGIN_DATA"])
{
// TODO
}

